# I was working on gulp workflow and i got this error

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
punith@punith-HP-Laptop-15s-eq2xxx:~/Documents/social-media-dashboard$ gulp
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:44:5
    at req_ (/home/punith/Documents/social-media-dashboard/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/home/punith/Documents/social-media-dashboard/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/punith/Documents/social-media-dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4H7x.png)
```

I started learning web development and i was working on a project using HTML,SCSS and JavaScript.In that tutorial video she used gulp workflow and i did has she instructed now i got did this error.And i also used chatgpt to solve but didn't work.Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/15250

Comment: FYI, I googled 'gulp ReferenceError'

Comment: The latest **gulp** version was released May 6, 2019.  That's a long time ago.  Instead of **gulp,** use CLI utilities (that are actively maintained) from the `"scripts"` section of your **package.json** file.